# Why is CAPM limited to a 'single period'?

Tags: shares, equity

CAPM (capital asset pricing model) has a 'single period' limitation. What does it mean practically?

```
The CAPM is based on a number of assumptions:
• well-diversified investors
• perfect capital market
• unrestricted borrowing or lending at the risk-free rate of interest
• all forecasts are made in the context of a single period transaction horizon.
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the Alpha & Beta and Mean & Standard Deviation change over time for each asset.

The Beta you calculate on Microsoft in 1990s is not remotely equal to the Beta you calcuate in 2010s.

Normally, such metrics are calculated using the past 12 months return, or some may use past 20-60 trading days return.

Comment: Pracitally, how does this affect, say, my intention to use beta to estimate NPV for a 5 year project? Textbooks suggest to use betas for companies in simialar line of business of the proposed project. Does 'single period' limitation mean I can't use 12 month beta for NPV dicscount factor? Why not calculate beta for last  5 years, which should give me muli-period beta, no?

Comment: "12 months" can be one period. But I would argue that the more recent data is more applicable to a future project - the beta from 5 years ago has much less relevance than the beta over the last 6 months. But you also need enough data to reduce random noise, so it's a trade-off.

Answer (score 1):

All of the variables (risk-free rate, beta, and market premium) change over time. You may find that one year into a project that one or more of those variables have changed and the project is no longer "profitable".

CAPM is just a *model*. It's not a law like gravity, and it's not the *only* way to evaluate something. It's a way to take something that may be incredibly difficult (or even impossible) to evaluate and use a much simpler method that can be evaluated more easily.

Note that it doesn't mean that you *can't* use CAPM to value multi-period projects, but it a *very simplistic* model and should be used *with caution* for longer projects. The longer the project, the more variables you need to consider, and may even require a *higher* expected return to reduce the risk of the model being inaccurate.

Comment: I do understand that it is a simplistic model. After all, it is a regression of past earnings data. My question is why the books mention 'single  period transaction horizon'. What is this ? 12 months ? One quarter? I mean you could calculate beta for last five years for a similar stock, which should give you expected return for the next five years for your project, granted , less accurate, perhaps. But wouldn't this 5 year beta also qualify as ' single period transaction horizon '?

Comment: "you could calculate beta for last five years for a similar stock, which should give you expected return for the next five years " this is where I disagree - you should use the most recent data you can to look forward - what happened 5 years ago is largely irrelevant when looking forward, but you have to look at enough history to reduce the sampling error.

Comment: So "one period" does not seem to be well defined, but I interpret is as maybe a quarter or a year _looking forward_. I don't think it applies to how far _back_ you go to calculate beta.

Comment: I would assume that the proposed project's 'time horizon' must match the 'time horizon' of the beta. For example, if I am assessing a future 5 year water matress project A's cost of equity, I must look for a beta of a water matress producing company B's for the last 5 years, no? If take B's last year return beta, I'd have a mistmatch.